# Quick remote logging system?

Tags: python, linux, logging, command-line

I want to be about to quickly insert some logging into some testing using either (Linux) command line or Python.  I don't want to do anything system wide (e.g. re-configuring syslogd).

I've done something like this before by doing:

wget URL/logme?im=module_name&msg=hello_world

And then just parsing the server log file.  It's a bit hackish and you have to URL encode all your data.  Surely someone has a better way by now.

Is there a better way to quickly get some remote logging?

Comment: Are you not willing to change Anthony on both sides system wide? Otherwise you can setup a rsyslog as the logger server and python 'loggerglue' to log from the client to the remote host.

Comment: I didn't know about loggerglue, that might help. I want something that I can setup without root permissions.  If I can run a syslog on a non privileged port, that should work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a remote syslog server: rsyslog or the python package loggerglue implements the syslog protocol as decribed in rfc5424 and rfc5425. . When you use a port above 1024 you can run it as a non-root user.

Within the python logging module you have a SyslogHandler which also supports the syslog remote logging.

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

my_logger = logging.getLogger('MyLogger')
my_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address = ('127.0.0.1',514))

my_logger.addHandler(handler)

my_logger.debug('this is debug')
my_logger.critical('this is critical')
```

Comment: Is it possible to send the log as a JSON to the SysLogHandler?

Comment: You can use [json-logging](https://github.com/bobbui/json-logging-python) and add the SysLogHandler to the JSON Logger.