# Sending Json Object string as syslog message in Python

Tags: python, json, syslog

I am using [this tool](https://github.com/imperva/mx-toolbox/blob/master/performance-monitoring/get_mx_stats.py) to get metrics on the appliance.

The script is using sockets to send syslog message, and I'm attempting to get it to send the message using native syslog functions.

I added the below code along but I cannot seem to get this working.

```
def sendSyslog2(jsonObj):
if (logHostAvailable["syslog"]==True):
    logging.info("SYSLOG REQUEST: "+json.dumps(jsonObj))
    try:
        syslog.openlog(facility=syslog.LOG_LOCAL5)
        syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_INFO, json.dumps(jsonObj))
    except:
        logging.error("syslog failed")
```

Even using test scripts is failing. I'm not well versed in python or programming but I can get by with some reference, any pointers in right direction appreciated.

Comment: I ended up using logging.handlers as recommended here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38907637/quick-remote-logging-system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38929289/1033927

You can use a remote syslog server: rsyslog or the python package loggerglue implements the syslog protocol as decribed in rfc5424 and rfc5425. . When you use a port above 1024 you can run it as a non-root user.

Within the python logging module you have a SyslogHandler which also supports the syslog remote logging.

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

my_logger = logging.getLogger('MyLogger')
my_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address = ('127.0.0.1',514))

my_logger.addHandler(handler)

my_logger.debug('this is debug')
my_logger.critical('this is critical')
```